# Differences using INNER and LEFT JOIN in secondary tables

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have a question about using three joins between 3 tables. Changing the type of JOIN between second and third tables, the result changes and I don't understand why.

TABLE1 NAME AND AGE

| NAME | AGE |
| --- | --- |
| BILL | 20 |
| JOHN | 25 |
| MARTHA | 34 |
| STEVE | 40 |
| EMILY | 30 |

TABLE2 NAME AND ID

| NAME | ID |
| --- | --- |
| BILL | 001S |
| JOHN | 002B |
| MARTHA | 001Z |

TABLE3 ID AND HOBBIES

| ID | HOBBIES |
| --- | --- |
| 001S | FOOTBALL |
| 002B | MUSIC |
| 001Z | VOLLEYBALL |

EXAMPLE1

```
SELECT NAME, HOBBIES
FROM TABLE1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.NAME = TABLE2.NAME
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE2.ID = TABLE3.ID
```

EXAMPLE2

```
SELECT NAME, HOBBIES
FROM TABLE1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.NAME = TABLE2.NAME
INNER JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE2.ID = TABLE3.ID
```

I want all the NAMES, no matter if they have HOBBIES or not. And this only happens in EXAMPLE1, in EXAMPLE2 the query returns the NAMES with HOBBIES, but I can't understand why it's not working with EXAMPLE2. The only difference is the INNER and that does not affect the relationship between table 1 and 2.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: *I want all the NAMES, no matter if they have HOBBIES or not.* If so then `names` column must be a base. For to collect all names you must use a subquery which will gather all names from tables 1 and 2 (use UNION). Then join all 3 tables to this subquery with LEFT JOIN.

Comment: [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"??](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46091641/3404097)

Comment: [Is it true that using INNER JOIN after any OUTER JOIN will essentially invalidate the effects of OUTER JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55111083/3404097)

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

Since you used INNER JOIN in your latter join:

```
INNER JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE2.ID = TABLE3.ID
```

This condition requires that the row include a non-NULL value for `TABLE2.ID`. This rules out any case where the join to `TABLE2` produced no matches.

You can solve this by doing an outer join to the pairing of `TABLE2` and `TABLE3`:

```
SELECT TABLE1.NAME, HOBBIES
FROM TABLE1
LEFT JOIN (TABLE2 INNER JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE2.ID = TABLE3.ID)
   ON TABLE1.NAME = TABLE2.NAME;
```

You can also solve it by using `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT TABLE1.NAME, HOBBIES
FROM TABLE2 INNER JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE2.ID = TABLE3.ID
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TABLE1 ON TABLE1.NAME = TABLE2.NAME;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still don't understand why INNER JOIN constrains LEFT JOIN between TABLE 1 and TABLE2, shouldn't they be independent? I mean, you have to solve the first JOIN first and then the second one, right?

Comment: Yes, but the second join requires that `TABLE2.ID` is not null.