# Conditions with Outer Join

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

In a where clause I want to return all records with an 'E' at the end of the CRSE_NUMB or all records that have an 'AS' code in  ASCD_CODE.

Is it all right to add this OR condition in the where statement for the SLRRASG table if it has an outer join?

```
select distinct
      SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM PIDM,
      SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE Term_Code, 
      SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_PTRM_CODE,
      SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME LNAME, 
      SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME FNAME, 
      SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID SID,
      SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_COLL_CODE_1,
     -- decode(SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_COLL_CODE_1, 'YC', 'Yale_College', 'SU', 'Visiting_Student') Student_Type, 
   --   SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE, 
   --   SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_LEVL_CODE LVL_Code, 
   --   SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_LEVL_CODE CRS_LVL, 
       SLRRASG.SLRRASG_ASCD_CODE Housing_Status,
    -- SLRRASG.SLRRASG_BEGIN_DATE, 
    -- SLRRASG.SLRRASG_END_DATE,
      SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE, 
      SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB,
      SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_CRN CRN,
    --  SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_TITLE,
    --  SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_ADD_DATE,
    --  SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_OTH_HR_LOW as "Credit",
    --  SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_BILL_HR, 
    --  SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_CREDIT_HR
    --SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_CREDIT_HR, 
    listagg(distinct goremal.goremal_email_address, ',')
from
  SATURN.SGBSTDN
  join SATURN.SFRSTCR
    on SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM = SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_PIDM
      and SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF = SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE
  join SATURN.SPRIDEN
    on SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM = SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM
  left join SATURN.SLRRASG
      on SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM = SLRRASG.SLRRASG_PIDM
         and SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF = SLRRASG.SLRRASG_TERM_CODE
         -- and  SLRRASG.SLRRASG_ASCD_CODE = 'AS'
 join SATURN.SSBSECT
  on SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = SSBSECT.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE
    and SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_CRN = SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRN
 join SATURN.SCBCRSE
  on SSBSECT.SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE = SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE
    and SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB = SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB
  left join GENERAL.GOREMAL
   on SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM = GOREMAL.GOREMAL_PIDM
    and GOREMAL.GOREMAL_EMAL_CODE = 'HAPP'
where
  SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID like '9%'
  and  SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = '202302'
  and SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_COLL_CODE_1 = 'SU'
  and SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND is null
  and SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE in ('RE', 'RW')
  and SSBSECT.SSBSECT_SSTS_CODE in ('A', 'E', 'O')
  and SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_PTRM_CODE in ('H4B', 'H5A', 'H5B', 'H10', 'H8', 'HSL', 'HND', 'HE3', 'HEL', 'H6', 'HFY', 'HWY')
  and (SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB not like '%E' or 
      SLRRASG.SLRRASG_ASCD_CODE = 'AS')
 --  and SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB not like '%E'
  and SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM = (
    select max(scbcrse_eff_term) from saturn.scbcrse xppd
    where
    xppd.scbcrse_subj_code = scbcrse.scbcrse_subj_code
    and
    xppd.scbcrse_crse_numb = scbcrse.scbcrse_crse_numb and xppd.scbcrse_eff_term <= ssbsect_term_code)
group by
   SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM,
  SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE, 
  SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_PTRM_CODE,
  SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME, 
  SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME, 
  SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID,
  SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_COLL_CODE_1,
   SLRRASG.SLRRASG_ASCD_CODE,
 SLRRASG.SLRRASG_BEGIN_DATE, 
 SLRRASG.SLRRASG_END_DATE,
  SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE, 
  SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB,
 SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_CRN
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` combined with `GROUP BY` raises many eye-brows.

Comment: What do you mean by “ if it is alright”? If your query returns the correct result then it is right, otherwise it is wrong

Comment: [Left Join With Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4752455/3404097) [Is it true that using INNER JOIN after any OUTER JOIN will essentially invalidate the effects of OUTER JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55111083/3404097) [Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097) [mre] [ask] [Help]

Comment: LEFT/RIGHT JOIN ON returns INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left/right table rows extended by NULLs. FULL gives INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left & right table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN ON is part of your OUTER JOIN ON. After a LEFT/RIGHT/FULL JOIN a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING needing some column(s) of the right/left/2 [sic] table(s) to be not NULL removes rows with introduced NULLs, leaving only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". Needing a non-NULL right/left column "turns FULL into RIGHT/LEFT". You have that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's perfectly okay to filter in the `WHERE` clause. Just make sure you include a condition for handling a NULL value due to the outer join if your logic requires it. You may not need it:

```
and (SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB not like '%E' or 
     SLRRASG.SLRRASG_ASCD_CODE = 'AS')
```

If SLRRASG_ASCD_CODE is NULL then the second filter will fail but the first might still succeed, and that may be what you want, in which case you're fine.  But if you want to treat NULL as the same as 'AS' then you should add:

```
and (SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB not like '%E' or 
     SLRRASG.SLRRASG_ASCD_CODE = 'AS' or
     SLRRASG.SLRRASG_ASCD_CODE IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add the filter to the join condition:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
       ON     t1.id = t2.id
          AND t2.ascd_code = 'AS'
WHERE  other_conditions
```

If you use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
       ON     t1.id = t2.id
WHERE  t2.ascd_code = 'AS'
AND    other_conditions
```

Then there must be a matched row for `t2` to be able to have an `ascd_code` that matches the filter and your query will effectively have an `INNER JOIN` and not an `OUTER JOIN` so is the same as:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN table2 t2
       ON     t1.id = t2.id
WHERE  t2.ascd_code = 'AS'
AND    other_conditions
```

If you do want to filter in the `WHERE` clause then you need to check if the row did not match in the `OUTER JOIN` and you can do that by checking if the columns(s) used in the join condition are `NULL`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
       ON     t1.id = t2.id
WHERE  (t2.id IS NULL OR t2.ascd_code = 'AS')
AND    other_conditions
```

---

If you want to filter on multiple conditions and they both must be true if the outer joins are matched then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
       ON     t1.id = t2.id
          AND t2.ascd_code = 'AS'
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3
       ON     t1.id = t3.id
          AND t3.crse_numb NOT LIKE '%E'
WHERE  other_conditions
```

or, if you want either: `t2.ascd_code = 'AS'` and `t3.crse_numb` to be anything; or `t2.ascd_code` to be anything and `t3.crse_numb` not end with `E` then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
       ON     t1.id = t2.id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3
       ON     t1.id = t3.id
WHERE  other_conditions
AND    (  t2.ascd_code = 'AS'
       OR t3.crse_numb NOT LIKE '%E' )
```

*Note: This will force either `t2` or `t3` to always be matched and whichever table is matched will effectively be `INNER JOIN`ed and the other table can be `OUTER JOIN`ed.*